# tr td jquery each previous td value is not saving in variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

In debit note if i alert sales invoice value `alert("sales" + si );` then it says:-

> undefined

why is that?

Why it is not saving value in `si`?

Any help?

My code

```
$('input[type=button]' ).click(function() {

    var trid = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id'); // table row ID 
    var grossProfit = 0;

    $("tr#"+trid).each(function( i ) { // row.

        $("td", this).each(function( j ) { // col.
            console.log("".concat("row: ", i, ", col: ", j, ", value: ", $(this).text()));

            //Sales Invoice.

            if ( j == 2) {  
                var si =  $(this).find("input").val(); 
                // if sales invoice not found/undefined.
                if (typeof si === "undefined") {
                    si = 0; // if sales invoice is not defined.
                }
                alert("sales" + si );
            }
            // Debit Note.
            if ( j == 3) {  
                var dn =  $(this).find("input").val(); // Debit note input value.
                //if debit note not found/undefined.
                if (typeof dn === "undefined") {
                    dn = 0; // if Debit Note is not defined.
                }
                alert("sales" + si );
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Single html row with input fields tr and td
share code with html
https://codeshare.io/21q4zj

Comment: add html mark up as well

Comment: Please add HTML too

Comment: HTML row with all tds https://codeshare.io/21q4zj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

To clarify who are thinking its a scope issue **its not**

JavaScript does [variable hoisting](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp) and all variable definition are brought to the top inside your function.

what JavaScript  does it initializes a variable to undefined when it assigns a memory to it.

If a variable is undefined it means the variable is not initialized.

A undefined (Never defined) variable in Javascript will give you **reference error**

https://jsfiddle.net/b5cbwufx/3/

**Solution**

Here the problem is that you are assigning the value `si = 0`

only if the condition `if (j == 2) {` is met that means when the condition  `if(j == 3){` is met the above condition will obliviously fail hence your si is never initialized to `0`

This code never executes

```
if ( j == 2) {  
  var si =  $(this).find("input").val(); 
  // if sales invoice not found/undefined.
  if (typeof si === "undefined") {
    si = 0; // if sales invoice is not defined.
  }
   alert("sales" + si );
}
```

so, your are getting undefined in the code

```
// Debit Note.
if (j == 3) { 
  var dn = $(this).find("input").val(); 

  if (typeof dn === "undefined") {
    dn = 0; // if Debit Note is not defined.
  }
  alert("sales" + si); // not defined as j==3 and not 2
}
```

try declaring them outside the if blocks at the top

```
var si=0,dn=0; //declare here

// // Sales Invoice.
if (j == 2) { 

  si = $(this).find("input").val();
  // if sales invoice not found/undefined.
  if (typeof si === "undefined") {
    si = 0; // if sales invoice is not defined.
  }
  alert("sales" + si);

} // scope ends

// Debit Note.
if (j == 3) { 
  dn = $(this).find("input").val(); // Debit note input value.

  if (typeof dn === "undefined") {
    dn = 0; // if Debit Note is not defined.
  }
  alert("sales" + si);
}
```